# Microsoft Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one settings table that is storing different setting keys for a app built using Microsoft Access
One of the settings key drives how many records should be seen in a dropdown list
The query behind the list is similar to the one below:

```
Select Top 3 id, name FROM tblRegular
```

Now, I want to achieve something like this:

```
Select Top (Select keyValue FROM tblSettings WHERE key="rowNumber") id, name FROM tblRegular
```

But, using it like this does not work as it fires errors
Could someone tell me if it can be done?

EDIT: The table structure looks similar to the one below:
tblRegular:

```
id  | name
1     'A'
2     'B'
3     'C'
```

tblSettings:

```
id  | key          | keyValue
1     'rowNumber'    2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would very much help.

Comment: In MS Access, you cannot select `top` values from 2 different tables with no relation between them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think the OP wants a dynamic `TOP` value, perhaps coming from another query.  Doable in SQL Server, but not sure about Access.

Comment: In SQL Server is possible, it works and it is tested.. but in Access I don't have a clue why it's generating errors..

Answer (score 1):

Consider the pure SQL solution using a correlated subquery to calculate a *rowCount* that is then used in outer query to filter by number of rows:

```
SELECT main.id, main.[name]
FROM
   (SELECT t.id, t.[name],
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM tblRegular sub 
           WHERE sub.[name] <= t.[name]) AS rowCount
    FROM tblRegular t) AS main
WHERE main.rowCount <= (SELECT Max(s.keyValue) FROM tblSettings s 
                        WHERE s.key = 'rowNumber')
```

Alternatively with the domain aggregate, `DMax()`:

```
SELECT main.id, main.[name]
FROM
   (SELECT t.id, t.[name],
          (SELECT Count(*) FROM tblRegular sub 
           WHERE sub.[name] <= t.[name]) AS rowCount
    FROM tblRegular t) AS main
WHERE main.rowCount <= DMax("keyValue", "tblSettings", "key = 'rowNumber'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax does fail in Access SQL, barking at "Select" with the (localised) message like:

> The SELECT sentence contains a reserved word or argument, that is
>   misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, just found out that using the Select statement as it was in the question would have triggered the errors mentioned. So, the approach that worked is to alter the .RowSource of the dropdown on form load and the query placed in the rowsource should look like:

```
Select Top (" & rowNr & ") id, name FROM tblRegular
```

where `rowNr` is fetched using another SQL query or even a DAO/ADO function to retrieve the value from the database

Comment: You should mention that you are using a coding language, namely VBA, to build an SQL query on the fly and not using pure SQL.